# Parsing the same string gives two different values

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to parse a string and remove the 'emojis' off it and keep the new lines.

So, I have this piece of code:

```
string text = "S H A V A . Est 2015\nBandung\nLine: @ubm5921j\nBbm: 7D2E6310\nFAST ORDER\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe";
MessageBox.Show(text);
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

The output of 'text' here is the following:

[image]

So, as you can see the new lines work fine and the end of it has 'emojis' and the next line it removes them PERFECTLY. So the result string will contain the same string with new lines and no emojis.

On another part of the program I have this code.

```
//uu.description is the same string as above 'text', 
//this is where I scrape directly from html
string text2 = uu.description; 
MessageBox.Show(text2);
string result2 = Regex.Replace(text2, @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

[image]

As you can see in this case, my text2 outputs the string in the format as it is, and the regex does absolutely nothing. The new lines don't work and the emojis are not removed.

I am very confused why it does work in my first case and not in the second case. I've been on this for hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: Try `string text2 = Regex.Unescape(uu.description);` and replace the characters with `@"\p{Cs}"`. Or check the scraping code: you get all the characters escaped at some point. Please show the HTML scraping code.

Comment: `string text2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(uu.description);`

Comment: `string text2 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(uu.description);` if you use .NET 4.0 and above

Comment: @stribizhev The scraping code is kind of too long to show. Basically, I have a web client and I use requestString() to download the page and then I scrape it off there. I tried `string lmao = Regex.Unescape(uu.description);` and then `lmao = Regex.Replace(testz, @"\p{Cs}", "");` but same result

Comment: @KhanhTO Thanks for the answer, my target framework in the properties shows .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, but I get an error that `The name 'HttpUtility does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: Try adding a reference to `System.Web` and importing the namespace with `using`

Comment: @KhanhTO I went to Refernces > .NET, but I can't find `System.Web` reference. There's only `System.Web.ApplicationServices` and `System.Web.Services`.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to set the Encoding to UTF8: `webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: it could be that you already reference it. Try importing the namespace

Comment: @stribizhev I just tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @KhanhTO Alright, I just imported it. My code is `string text2 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(uu.description);` `string result2 = Regex.Replace(text2, @"\p{Cs}", "");` but still it doesn't work. Both text2 and result2 show the same text with no new lines happening.

Comment: Are you sure they are? Since the final results are different, there is a difference. Please hover other the `uu.Message` in the IDE and check what the string looks like. Make a screenshot, if possible.

Comment: @stribizhev Can you explain me how to do this? When I hover over uu.description in the IDE, it just shows `ClassName.description`.

Comment: If you work in Visual Studio, when debugging, hover the cursor over the code, right on the `Description`.

Comment: Change .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to 
.NET Framework 4 
The Client Profile is a smaller limited .NET library and will cause issues such as certain parts of the library to be missing.

Comment: Your `MessageBox.Show` calls are showing us that `text` is *not* the same as `text2`. It isn't the regex's fault.

Comment: @Rawling Yes, I do not blame Regex. I am confused why text and text2 are different, with the same text. The new lines are not working in the second case for some reason.

Comment: In that case, you need to show us how you're roundtripping `uu.description`.

Comment: @Rawling Can you explain how to to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Show us where `uu` comes from...

Comment: @Rawling uu comes from a class I have written. As I have previously written a comment, the code is kinda too long, so I'll give you the steps I use. I have a WebClient and I use the `requestString()` function to download the source. Then I parse it. I'll give you the exact URL I use for this post: https://instagram.com/shavahouse/. My program scrapes the bio in the profile `"biography":"S H A V A . Est 2015\nBandung\nLine: @ubm5921j\nBbm: 7D2E6310\nFAST ORDER\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe"` this particular thing. If you need the full source, I can upload it on pastebin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86804/discussion-between-user5204184-and-rawling).

Comment: Please post the code you are using to download site contents. That is where we should start looking for the culprit. I have just tried, and - with UTF8 as Webclient encoding - got `FAST ORDERрџ‘‡рџЏѕрџ‘‡рџЏѕ"` in the response.

Comment: @stribizhev I have fixed the problem, by using Regex.Unescape() as you suggested above. Posted my solution in the answers. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user5204184: Actually, that was exactly my suggested solution. I think I should have posted the answer.

Comment: @stribizhev That's correct. I have written that in the answer itself. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: You already got credits, let it be. Just next time please let know if the suggested solution works for you and give credit to those who earned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it. My fixed code looks like this:

```
string text2 = uu.description;
string result2 = Regex.Replace(Regex.Unescape(text2), @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

For some reason, the parsed string was with an additional `\`, looking like this `\\n`. I would like to thank @stribizhev for his idea! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try tis

```
           string text = "S H A V A . Est 2015\nBandung\nLine: @ubm5921j\nBbm: 7D2E6310\nFAST ORDER\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe\ud83d\udc47\ud83c\udffe";
            string output = string.Join("",text.Select(x => Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(new char[] { x })).Select(y => (y[1] << 8) + y[0]).Where(y => y < 256).Select(z => ((char)z).ToString()));
​
```

Output from code

```
S H A V A . Est 2015
Bandung
Line: @ubm5921j
Bbm: 7D2E6310
FAST ORDER​
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? It gives the same output as text.

Comment: I converted string charactedrs to int[] so I can test if a character is < 256 (ASCII) or >= 256 (Unicode) and removed all characters >=256.  Then converted back to string.

Comment: I see. My goal is to keep the new lines and remove the emoji only. So \n has to stay in the string. And also, I think the problem is that the new lines are not working, they appear as normal letters, rather than new lines.

Comment: I'm not changing '\n' in my code.  The new lines are working in windows. You can verify that '\n' is working by pasting string into notepad.  I added to my answer the actual results.